# Efficiently write two arrays to a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

As per the title, I wish to write two column vectors to a file (format: 3 digit hex, tab, 4 digit hex). I think I can do it with the following:

```
for i=1:size(imgA,1)
   fprintf(fid, ['%03X %04X \n'], imgA(i,1), imgB(i,1));
end
```

For a large sized vector this is taking a long time, I'm sure there is a probably a better way of doing this?

I thought about restructuring the two arrays into one (interleaving every second entry) and writing it out in one go - but I can't seem to get that to work

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to work for my needs:

fprintf(fid, ['%03X %04X \n'], [imgA(:,1), imgB(:,1)]');

Comment: irrelevant but good to know: you don't need the brackets around the string argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
fprintf(fid, ['%03X %04X \n'], [imgA(:,1);imgB(:,1)]);
```

I think this is faster.

Comment: Its definitely faster, but its prints all of imgA using the specified format, and then all of imgB

Comment: See you already found the solution. My code misses a transpose.

Comment: Yes, thanks Daniel. Seeing as this is so close to what I needed I'm happy to mark this as the answer, if you'd like to edit your post above and add the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would try `dlmwrite`:

```
delim = repmat('   ',length(imgA(:,1)),1);
output = [ imgA(:,1) , delim , imgB(:,1) ]
dlmwrite('test.txt',output,'')
```

Hex formats are already strings, so it's simple, but you need a delimiter matrix to get some space between your vectors.

---

**Example:**

```
tic
A = dec2hex( randi(10000,10000,1) );
B = dec2hex( randi(10000,10000,1) );
delim = repmat('     ',length(A),1);

output = [A, delim, B];
dlmwrite('test.txt',output,'');
toc
```

quite fast I guess:

> Elapsed time is 0.860588 seconds.

For 100000 elements:

> Elapsed time is 8.652231 seconds.

so the time obviously scales linear with the number of elements. I don't know if it is finally faster than `fprintf`

---

If you wouldn't have the hex format, but decimal numbers this approach would be definetely faster:

```
A = randi(10000,100000,1) ;
B = randi(10000,100000,1) ;
C = [A, B];
save('test.txt','C','-tabs','-ascii');
```

assuming `A` and `B` are columnvectors, otherwise transpose them.

> Elapsed time is 0.155126 seconds.